# Bad Situation importing/exporting img files - mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqlimport

I inherited a poorly created mysql database and now I need to migrate data to a new server.

Long story short, I need to keep it stored this way and I use phpmyadmin.  Know of any tools to help the migration of this 1.2GB mysql table?

Hope I don't get slaughtered for this post...

Comment: Why would you get slaughtered? (Backup/Restore)?

Comment: I meant get slaughtered by comments on here because the files are going to stay stored on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench (free as in beer, free as in speech) has dump and restore features.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-server-data-dump-tab.html

Phpmyadmin and other admin tools also have those features, but web-based tools may not handle such a large table properly.

Dump your big table from your old server to a file on your desktop machine. Restore it to the new server. It may take overnight. So what? You only have to do it once (unless you mess it up the first time). Side benefit:  you'll have a backup of your old table that you can put onto a DVD-RW and throw in your desk drawer.

You might have to segment the dump process by selecting rows a few million at a time.  That's probably a good idea, because then you can restart the process if it crashes.

There are some tools (sqlyog) that can copy data from one server to another directly, as well.

Happy data wrangling.

Comment: There are image files, only 1.2GB worth - for some reason, I can't finish the entire upload process, but I downloaded just fine.  Upload only gets me about 66-70 entries inserted.

Comment: By "image files" I presume you mean a BLOB (binary large object) column containing images, correct?  Are your 60-70 inserted rows correct?  If so, was there an error message issued when the upload process stopped?  phpmyadmin isn't great for this high volume job, because it has to upload stuff with HTTP POST, then buffer it and push it to mySQL.  There are timeouts and POST size limits to get in your way.